# Component in one third part of Wordpress article

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm looking for a plugin who can add a personalized component in an article automaticly, like in the picture below.

[Wordpress article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGKnp.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-shortcode/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-content/

Will do the trick for you :)

Comment: Please do not post answers to questions that are clearly in violation of SO community guidelines.  You only encourage those kinds of off-topic posts.  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a theme like DIVI or a content builder like Thrive content builder as they have these kind of customization options